# Client only Meteor app only displays iron:router screen with Cordova

Tags: cordova, meteor

I'm trying to build a simple mobile game and I'm using Meteor + Cordova for that. So far when I run it on localhost:3000 it works jut fine but when I try to deploy to Android all i get is this: 
[image: My app on Android]

I have a `router.coffee` file in an `app/lib` like this:

```
Router.route '/', ->
  @render 'home'
  return
```

Since so far I'm only doing the client side and not doing the serve side yet, is there anything I'm missing? How exactly to I run the command `meteor run android-device`, what options for `<server>` and `<port>`?